# C# Open a void after async void completed

Tags: c#

When I press 6 in the console it opens the async void Mes(). Now, when it did it's job I want to go back to my static void Menu(). When I press 1 it should open the next async void I created, but after I typed in the number and hit enter, the console closes. Watch the code below.

Code of the async void that completed

```
public static async void Mes()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter username: ");
            var hg = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your message: ");
            var mc = Console.ReadLine();
            var uname = await api.GetUserAsync(hg);
            var id = uname.Value.Pk.ToString();
            var ms = await api.SendDirectMessage(id, null, mc);
            Console.WriteLine(ms.Succeeded ? "Successfully sent" : "Couldn't be sent\n\t" + ms.Info.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Menu();
        }
```

And now the static void Menu() opens, but after I hit a number the console closes

```
public static void Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 4");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 5");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 6");
            string ff = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ff == "1")
            {
                OS();
            }

            if (ff == "2")
            {
                SS();
            }

            if (ff == "3")
            {
                SV();
            }

            if (ff == "4")
            {
                COL();
            }

            if (ff == "5")
            {
                Upl();
            }

            if (ff == "6")
            {
                Mes();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Append `Console.ReadKey()` to the bottom of the `Main` method.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov now after I hit a number nothing happens, but the console doesn't close.

Comment: You need to use the key that is returned by `Console.ReadKey()` to actually switch on the key.
To go back to the Menu method you need something like a `while(true)` loop from which you break out manually.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot ok gonna try.